# Sending user results by Email

Tags: java, android

Hi I am wondering is there a way of sending the user an email (from my Gmail address) with results of calculations that occurs within the app itself?

For example a form is filled out with values for electricity rates and these rates are then computed and processed into information on savings for a particular product.

What I have is a custom alert box popup with the results and a button saying email me the results and then a EditText becomes visible below asking for the email address of the user.

Is this possible or would a simple notification be easier to do?

Comment: Do you want to automatically send mail or open "new mail" pre filled form in the gmail app?

Comment: I would like to automatically send the mail but with the results the user entered into the form. I would prefer to do this without gmail app opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it [via a form](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-email-intent/) or by using the [JavaMail API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-app) or you could use an [existing email client from the phone](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/how-to-send-an-email-from-your-android-application/).

Comment: Thanks I just used the third link to send an email from my own email client to myself, is there any way of doing this without gmail opening?

Comment: Glad the links helped. If you use the example the second link you could do that. Have a look at [this JavaMail Project](http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/). There is also a blog post [here](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android), which goes into a bit more detail on how to implement what you want, using the JavaMail library.